# Can you find the missing number?

Tags: number-sequence

Here's 3 number puzzles/series. I'll give hints tomorrow if noone is able to solve them

11, 31, 71, 91, 32, ?

1, 1, 2, 6, 36, 44, ?

IF, 132 = 72
     208= 200
     390=288

```
 then what does, 
 8932= ?
```

Answer (score 2):

second:

> 440

because:

> +0, *2, +4, *6, +8, *10

third:

> 968

because:

> sum of the digits squared and multiplied by 2

Comment: Yes you're correct

Comment: 3rd is correct!

Answer (score 1):

The first sequence

> Reversed is 11, 13, 17, 19, 23... which are prime numbers

So the next term is

> 92

Comment: Yes you're correct

Comment: Hint to the last one: involves squaring.